# Rect in Raphael JS doesn't have the same stroke width in all the sides

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

In this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pgschr/17hscxnL/22/) I have a Raphael JS paper with a rect. If you zoom in you will see that the bottom and right lines of the Raphael rect are wider:

[image]

How to fix this rect to have the same width in all the sides? I have this problem in Chrome, IE and Firefox.

```
var w = 500, h = 120;
var paper = Raphael("the_canvas", w, h); 

paper.rect(0,0,90,20)
  .attr({'stroke-dasharray': '-', 'stroke': '#303030', 'stroke-width': 1 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason they look different is actually due to the manner in which the default SVG css property `overflow` is set to `hidden`. If you for instance add the following rule:

```
svg {
  overflow: visible !important;
}
```

Both rectangles look the same, but they look like the lower part of you Raphael rectangle.

To achieve the crispness caused by the clipping of the `oveflow` property on your standard SVG node on both rectangles you can use the following CSS rule:

```
rect {
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

That in combination with the first rule produce something close to the desired result.

Here is a fork of your fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/saxpnz6b/

and a snippet:

```js
var w = 500, h = 120;
var paper = Raphael("the_canvas", w, h); 

paper.rect(0,0,90,20)
  .attr({'stroke-dasharray': '-', 'stroke': '#303030' });
```

```css
#div1 {
  margin: 20px;
} 

svg {
  overflow: visible !important;
}

rect {
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.3.0/raphael.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">
  <svg width="90" height="20">
     <rect width="90" 
           height="20" 
           style="fill:#ffffff;stroke-dasharray: 3,1;stroke-width:1; stroke: #303030" shape-rendering="crispEdges"/>
   </svg>

   <div id="the_canvas"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As you say, I get closer to the desired result, but I'm still getting some sides wider than others. Why does this happen if Raphael is supposed to generate pure SVG?

Comment: I ended up using `overflow: visible` only, that gave me the same width in all the sides